# Do Vue instances have to be destroyed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, garbage-collection

I'm dynamically creating Vue instances within a legacy JS project that creates and manipulates elements with VanillaJS. I'm wondering if the instances really have to be destroyed explicitly or if its fine to lose their reference and they will be garbage collected automatically like any JS object?

Comment: It really depends, a lot, but for the vast majority of cases I think destroying them is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

There are only two scenarios I can think of where you might want to destroy your instances manually.

**Scenario one** is if you use the same HTML element for more than one component. In that case, if you can add other elements to the page you can just do it and use `v-if` to have Vue destroy them when they are no longer needed.

For example, if you have this `<div>`:

```
<div id="content">...</div>
```

And use it for two different components, let's say `A` and `B`, and you have to mount and destroy them in your `<div>` depending on the situation, you might as well use two `<div>`s, like this:

```
<div id="content-a" v-if="usingA">...</div>
<div id="content-b" v-if="usingB">...</div>
```

And whenever a given component becomes unnecessary you can just set `usingA` or `usingB` to false.

**Scenario two** is when for some reason or another you can't use `v-if`. In that case I believe you probably have to manually call `$destroy`, but I really can't think of any possible reason why you wouldn't be able to use `v-if` in the first place.